# Subversion for Dummies

Tags: svn, configuration

I'm doing a little CakePHP project for a company in another country.  Part of it is definitely going to necessitate working on files which they have under Subversion version control.  The problem is, I've used Subversion but I'm not an expert: with the information I've been given, I've failed miserably to set things up.

To make matters even more complicated, even *they're* not certain they've configured things correctly to grant me access.  With two groups who don't really know what they're doing trying to figure out what's going on independently, we're not likely to get very far in a hurry, especially with an 8-hour time difference to stop us talking it through on the phone!  So I need to know one of two things, either (a) how to get myself hooked into their Subversion repository based on the information given below, or (b) what I need to ask them to do to get me up and running.

This is what I've been given (mutatis mutandis):

```
svn address in the form svn://intranet.companyname.com
username
password

paths to "look at" in the form  /trunk/sites/extranet and /trunk/sites/dev.companyname.com
```

If anyone can walk me through how to get myself synched up to an existing repository, I promise to be bountiful with my upvotes!  Thank you!

(I'm using Mac OSX if that makes a difference; I don't know if I should get myself a subversion client or if I can just get it done from the command line...)

Comment: automation is key. use TortoiseSVN, or your life will be hell.

Comment: You can try Versions (http://versionsapp.com/) or Cornerstone (http://www.zennaware.com/cornerstone/), both graphical Subversion clients which have trial versions for download. TortoiseSVN is Windows only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible to do it all from the command line, but a client is going to be a lot easier. The steps are going to be something like:

- Create a branch by copying trunk
- Check out branch
- Work on code, checking into branch reguarly
- Regularly merge changes from trunk into branch
- reintegrate branch to trunk once done

At least this is how i typically work, using a feature branch, you could work directly in trunk in which case its easier

- check out
- work
- check in, resolving any conflicts
- update your working copy and work some more

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the "svn://" URL isn't going to help you across the Internet. Maybe ssh+svn, but preferably https:// . If you've got an https:// URL, then you can actually just open it in a web browser -- it should let you actually browse around in the repository. If you've got ssh+svn, then only an ssh client is going to work.

Answer (score 1):

What they have done is given you an svn reference.  You can access SVN in a couple of different ways.  The svn syntax is one of them.  The other is via http/https.

In my experience, svn syntax like that is usually given for access via something like ssh.  But you have to have ssh setup first.  And you have to be able to access their servers from yours.  The best way is to get them to give https access to their svn repo by hosting it via apache.

Check out the red book, and specifically 
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd

Once you have access setup via https (i highly recommend https) you'll be able to hit the repo using something like TortoiseSVN.  The svn command line is usable.  Just takes a little getting used to.  I have used both and prefer the command-line when I am in linux.

Checkout, and do your work.